# UL, LI: List is not getting update, once source data model is change

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Development Environment: Angular 6
Functionality: Drag and Drop

I have created a drag drop example in Angular6. I have not used any angular directive. HTML5 provides some method to achieve that, using the same.

i have an array object(i.e. selectedList), with the help of this object i am iterating over and creating list. EX:

```
     <li draggable="true"  *ngFor="let item of selectedList" class="k-item" id="{{item['flD_NUM']}}_{{item['tablE_NME']}}"
                        (drop)="drop('list_columns_selected',$event)" 
                        (dragenter)= "dragEnter('list_columns_selected',$event)" 
                        (dragleave)= "dragLeave('list_columns_selected',$event)" 
                        (dragstart)="dragStart('list_columns_selected',item,$event)" 
                        (dragend)="dragend('list_columns_selected',$event)"
                        (click)="selectList('list_columns_selected',item,$event)"
                        (drag) = "drag('list_columns_selected',$event)"
                        (dragover) = "isDropAllowed('list_columns_selected',$event)"
                        >
```

But: Once i update the array object(i.e. selectedList), it does not reflect in list.

My requirement is, once i update the array object, list should re-render on latest data.

**Note:** if it is a simple list, it's working fine. But once we added Drag & drop to the list, then it is not changing.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: set your `selectedList` as an *Observable*

Comment: It doesn't help.
if it is a simple list, it's working fine. But once we added Drag & drop to the list, then it is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crude, but effective, way of injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` into component and explicitly calling the `detectChanges()` method after updating the contents of selectedList.

Another idea - are you mutating the selectedList (`push()`, `splice()`, things like that), or are you replacing it with a new version (`this.selectedList = [...this.selectedList, newElem].filter(/* some filter */)`)? If the former, Angular does only a shallow comparison of the value, and mutations like `push()` slip below the radar.

Comment: i am using :(this.selectedList = [...this.selectedList, newElem].filter(/* some filter */).

Comment: if it is a simple list, it's working fine. But once we added Drag & drop to the list, then it is not changing.

Comment: Does the `detectChanges` workaround work? Overwriting the array *should* work anyway. How is the `drop` method implemented?